# Firebase: How to the get the user email address after Google Auth Method

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase provides 2 advanced option in their dashboard to manage duplicate authentication:

First, **Multiple accounts per email address**
Second, **One account per email address**

Auth with "One account per email address" is working as expected but when I try "Multiple accounts per email address", the Auth callback doesn't return email address of the user (i.e. null) nor the emailVerified field is true.

What may be the possible reason? Is this glitch voluntarily implemented by Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, the top level email `currentUser.email` has to be unique. In that mode "multiple accounts per email", you can have multiple accounts with that email, so this is not set in this mode (except for password accounts) as the user identifier would clash. You can always set that via `currentUser.updateEmail' API but the Auth backend will enforce the uniqueness. You can access the provider email via the providerData on the user`currentUser.providerData[0].email`. If you are using Google as a provider and don't get the Google email in the web signInWithPopup/Redirect flow, make sure you ask the 'email' OAuth scope.

Comment: In mode "multiple accounts per email", I tried with Twitter & Facebook. It returns the email address as usual. So good to go with "One account per email address" instead of making complex logics for storing emails. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Try this: It't work for me:  `val email = user?.providerData?.get(1)?.email`